# Nginx server block

Tags: nginx, server

Hy everyone,
I have a little problem with nginx server block and I hope that someone from here will know the solution to it.

This is how my configuration looks like:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com;
}

server{
    listen 80;
    server_name *.example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name .example.com;
...
}
```

So the first block is normal http redirecting to https second is catching subdomains and third is where location blocks are etc.

My problem is that when the second block catches the request would like to add /admin to URL so it would be subdomain.example.com/admin but i have to check if it already has /admin so i don't get something like this subdomain.example.com/admin/admin.

I tried `server_name *.example.com$` and `server_name ~.example.com(=<id>.*)` then `if ($id = '')` and hundreds of combinations and didn't get anything usefull.

Did anyone here had similar problem and solved it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name *.example.com;
    if ($request_uri !~ ^/admin/) { 
        return 301 https://$host/admin$request_uri;
    }
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Code snippets on their own are not very informative. Please explain what the code does, why you wrote it that way, and how you expect it to work

Comment: Sorry, i deleted my question before i read yours, I managed it to work, it was obviously some kind of my error